# javamail issue on server but working locally

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've been struggling for a moment now to send mails from my ubuntu server. Weird thing is, it's working perfectly on my mac on a local tomcat instance.

Here is my implementation :

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mydomain.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("myaccount@mail.com", "mypassword");
                }
    });
    session.setDebug(true);
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myaccount@mail.com","Team"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("test@mail.com"));
        message.setSubject(title);
        message.setContent(htmlContent,"text/html");

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        logger.error("Could not send email, MessagingException : "+e.getMessage());
        throw new CouldNotSendEmailException();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        logger.error("Could not send email, UnsupportedEncodingException : "+e.getMessage());
        throw new CouldNotSendEmailException();
    }
```

What annoys me is that the output logs from javamail is the same between my server and locally and there is no error:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mydomain.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 ns0.ovh.net ssl0.ovh.net. You connect to mail619.ha.ovh.net ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.mydomain.com", port: 587

EHLO 185.12.xxx.xxx
250-ns0.ovh.net ssl0.ovh.net. You connect to mail619.ha.ovh.net
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250 SIZE 109000000
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=LOGIN", arg "PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "109000000"
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<no-reply@mydomain.com>
250 ok
RCPT TO:<test@mail.com>
250 ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   test@mail.com
DATA
354 go ahead
From: Team <no-reply@mydomain.com>
To: test@mail.com
Message-ID: <2101030206.0.1423948092063.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>
Subject: Warning
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!-- body of the mail -->

.
250 ok 1423948092 qp 12281
QUIT
221 ns0.ovh.net ssl0.ovh.net. You connect to mail619.ha.ovh.net
```

What i've done so far

- checking my spams (like a thousand times, just in case...)
- tried other ports like 465, and 25-> same problem, working locally but not on server
- open 587 port with iptables

  iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT

  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT

I'm starting to feel a bit desperate now, if anyone got an idea, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in your mail server.  It accepts the message but then queues it and never delivers it, or throws it away.  You need to look at the logs and configuration of your mail server.

BTW, there's a [much newer version of JavaMail available](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).